# Blur the entire html when the sub-menu is open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a submenu using HTML and CSS. The elements of the submenu open when hovered on the elements of nav-list. I need help figuring out how to blur the HTML's main content when the nav-list hovers and sub-menu is open. When open, the submenu will have a picture below it and multiple pictures and classes further down. The current code does blur the HTML, but the problem is, to blur the entire HTML, I need to add each class below the submenu to CSS individually.

```css
nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: .7rem;
  padding-left: 1.1rem;
}

.nav-list li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-list>li>a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1.3rem 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 3.89rem;
  left: -4rem;
  width: 82.5rem;
  height: 35rem;
  z-index: 5000;
}

.sub-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 3rem 40px 0 40px;
}

.nav-list>li:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.nav-list>li:hover>a::after {
  width: 100%;
}


/* CSS for blur effect */

.blurred::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  filter: blur(5px);
  /* adjust the blur amount */
  z-index: 900;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="">XYZ<br>123</a>
  </div>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li>
        <a href="">Men</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">shirts</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <img></img>
  <img></img>
  <img></img>
  <img></img>
</div>

<footer>
  1
</footer>

<script>
  var subMenu = document.querySelector('.sub-menu');
  var main = document.querySelectorAll('main');
  subMenu.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    main.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.classList.add('blurred');
    });
  });
  subMenu.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    main.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.classList.remove('blurred');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: _"but the problem is, to blur the entire HTML, I need to add each class below the submenu to CSS individually"_ - what exactly do you mean you mean by that? Are you talking about the `main` class, that you are currently looping over, to add the `blurred` class to those elements? I suppose you could just loop over `body > *` instead, which will select all of body's children ...?

Comment: It's strange that your `nav` has `class="main"`. What for? Wouldn't it have something like `class="nav"` ? In any case, whatever you do, you must have distinction between the areas of your layout so that can target things appropriately. You could have `<div id="myMainContent" class="blurrable">` as a starting point, and in your blur function, just target anything with class `"blurrable". You can make up your own words for this. As well, FYI, there is a word "blur" in HTML/JS context (having to do with focus of items), keep it in mind. You would be better off using a word like ... "smudge" lol.

Comment: Side note: I did something similar in the past (blurring-out content while a menu was open), and I just needed to target my content wrapper and give it a visual effect; I did not need to make 100's of classes all over the place. Depending on how you do the blurring effect, this may hit framerate a bit especially on old devices and computers.

Comment: @Thor The dog: Does the answer below answer your question? If so would you care to accept it (see gray checkmark)? If not, please add some more details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add the blurred class to the main container div, all content will be blurred in it.

Demo for blur on hover over hamburger (you can change that to blur only on sub-menu hover). There is a 2 sec delay on mouse-out to that you have time to scroll down to see the blurred image:

```js
const hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger');
const main = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
hamburger.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  main.classList.add('blurred');
});
hamburger.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  setTimeout(() => main.classList.remove('blurred'), 2000);
});
```

```css
.blurred {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" id="navbar">
  NAVBAR mouse over to blur ==> &nbsp; <span id="hamburger">☰</span>
  <hr />
</div>

<div class="main" id="mainContainer">
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam iaculis blandit felis vel hendrerit. Morbi nunc augue, pellentesque eu laoreet in, bibendum nec sem.</p>
  <ul><li>In eu libero eget nulla laoreet aliquet in quis augue.</li><li>Praesent vulputate leo tellus, quis eleifend purus viverra vitae.</li><li>Phasellus eget augue venenatis, facilisis nulla sed, consequat lorem.</li></ul>
  <p>Duis sapien diam, dignissim quis imperdiet eget, hendrerit nec nulla. Nam nisi purus, ultrices nec fringilla vitae, interdum vitae nunc.</p>
  <p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x90/000000/FFFFFF.png?text=This+is+an+embedded+image" /></p>
  <p>Integer lobortis tellus a orci ultrices, at varius risus fermentum. Maecenas maximus elit sit amet varius facilisis. Morbi molestie rutrum eros, id molestie dui maximus in. Etiam fermentum felis eu vehicula euismod.</p>
</div>

<footer>
  <hr />
  FOOTER
</footer>
```